# R rename multiple columns with wildcard with rename_with()

Tags: r, rename

library(tidyverse)

I am looking to rename bunch columns and I tried to use rename_at() or rename_with() in R but not much success, can someone help? Thank you very much for your help.

Original data frame column names

```
tibble(
AAA_BBB1_P1_Elev = as.double(),
AAA_BBB2_P2_Elev = as.double(),
AAA_BBB2_P3_Elev = as.double()
)
```

Want to change the column names to

```
tibble(
`BBB1-P1E` = as.double(),
`BBB1-P2E` = as.double(),
`BBB1-P3E` = as.double()
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `rename_all` with `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
tbl2 <- tbl1 %>%
     rename_all(~ str_replace_all(str_replace(., '^[^_]+_(.*)_(.)[^.]+$', "\\1\\2"), '_', "-"))
```

-output

```
tbl2
# A tibble: 0 x 3
# … with 3 variables: `BBB1-P1E` <dbl>, `BBB2-P2E` <dbl>, `BBB2-P3E` <dbl>
```

#### data

```
tbl1 <- structure(list(AAA_BBB1_P1_Elev = numeric(0), AAA_BBB2_P2_Elev = numeric(0), 
    AAA_BBB2_P3_Elev = numeric(0)), row.names = integer(0), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Not quite...but inspired by your answer I found a work-around

```
remove <- c("AAA_BBB[0-9]_", "lev", "_")

tibble(
  AAA_BBB1_P1_Elev = as.double(),
  AAA_BBB2_P2_Elev = as.double(),
  AAA_BBB2_P3_Elev = as.double()
) %>%
  rename_all(~ str_remove_all(., paste(remove, collapse = "|"))) %>%
  rename_at(vars(ends_with("E")), ~ paste0("BBB1-", .x))

# A tibble: 0 x 3
# ... with 3 variables: `BBB1-P1E` <dbl>, `BBB1-P2E` <dbl>, `BBB1-P3E` <dbl>
```

Comment: @Nick The solution I posted was based on the occurence of patterns i.e we are removing the first word followed bythe `_` and the `_` with Elev at the end

Comment: @Nick I think the update should work now.  I overlooked the E at the end

Comment: Thanks @akrun, to keep it consistent with other columns (not shown), I need the format to be 'BBB1-P1E',  'BBB1-P2E' etc and that's why the original solution does not work

Comment: @Nick sorry, I didn't see that earlier.  Updated

Comment: Thanks @akrun, the updated solution works beautifully! Definitely more elegant than my work-around! Thanks, I will accept the solution.

Comment: @Nick Sorry, my eye sight is bad, sometimes I don't see it clearly

Comment: No worries @akrun :-) Thank you very much for your help on this

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by akrun's answer, I came up with a work-around...

```
remove <- c("AAA_BBB[0-9]_", "lev", "_") 

tibble(
AAA_BBB1_P1_Elev = as.double(), 
AAA_BBB2_P2_Elev = as.double(), 
AAA_BBB2_P3_Elev = as.double()
) %>% 
rename_all(~ str_remove_all(., paste(remove, collapse = "|"))) %>% 
rename_at(vars(ends_with("E")), ~ paste0("BBB1-", .x)) 

# A tibble: 0 x 3 
# ... with 3 variables: BBB1-P1E <dbl>, BBB1-P2E <dbl>, BBB1-P3E <dbl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R option :

```
names(df) <- sub('\\w+_(\\w+)_(\\w+)_.*', '\\1-\\2E', names(df))
names(df)
#"BBB1-P1E" "BBB2-P2E" "BBB2-P3E"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Data on people tested on two occasions was given as

```
Data %>%
  select(Identifier, contains('eq5d'),-EQ5D3L_Combined) %>%
  names()
```

which gave this list of names.

> "Identifier"      "EQ5D3L_Item_1"   "EQ5D3L_Item_2"
> "EQ5D3L_Item_3"   "EQ5D3L_Item_4"   "EQ5D3L_Item_5"
> "EQ5D3L_VAS"      "EQ5D3L_Item_1_2" "EQ5D3L_Item_2_2"
> "EQ5D3L_Item_3_2" "EQ5D3L_Item_4_2" "EQ5D3L_Item_5_2"
> "EQ5D3L_VAS_2"

The '_2' was the second measurement occasion, and I needed to put '_1' at the end of the variable from the first occasion.

To fix this I used rename_with as follows

```
Data %>%
   select(Identifier, contains('eq5d'),-EQ5D3L_Combined) %>% 
   rename_with(~ifelse(!str_ends(.x,'[0-9]'),
                       str_c(.x,'_1'),
                       .x)) %>%
    names()
```

The !str_end picks out variable names which did *not* end with a number, as a logical vector. The ifelse applies the rename_with only to those which did not end in a number, and the str_c adds '_1' to those - so I now have my variable named correctly for an easy pivot_longer.